# Printing the same column twice

Tags: sql, phppgadmin

How can I print the 'ID' column twice. I've already got it in the start of the table, and also want it to  also print out as the last column again for easy viewing purposes.

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES
ADD ID int;
```

'ID already exists'

Also, when I update 'ID' I want both columns to be updated at once.

Thank you

Comment: "Printing" should generally be handled by the client rather than in queries. Including the data twice increases the amount of data the database has to handle, the amount of data sent across the network, and the amount of data the client must unpack; in addition to all that, as GMB's answer notes, having multiple fields with the same name can often be problematic for database access libraries.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have another copy of a column, you can always use it in the SELECT statement for more than once

```
SELECT ID, ID
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

If you insist in add it to the table structure, you have to change the name

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES
ADD ID2 int;
```

To update them both, you have to specify that in the update statement

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
SET ID = /*Whatever*/
,ID2 = /*Whatever*/
```

OR

you can create a trigger to update ID2 every time ID is updated

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a new column to the table. Instead, you can fetch it twice when `select`ing from the table:

```
select
    id,
    -- other columns here
    id
from employees
```

Please note that, depending on your client, having two columns with the same name in your resultset *could* cause issues (for example, if you are fetching records as an associative array, only one of the two occurences of the column will appear in the array).